# Android Studio Multi-Windows for One Project

Tags: android, android-studio, multi-window

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to open two windows of Android Studio with both having the same project. I know you can drag tabs out, but that allows you to only edit that one file. I want two **fully-featured** windows with each being able to see the Project Files/Structure.

I don't want to just split the editor, I want a separate window.

I want two of these windows, with both "looking" at the same project:
[image]

I don't want another one of these windows, as I can't view the project structure and change that, and it's hard to change it to a different file in this view:
[image]

Comment: Note:- If the intent is to spread the windows across multiple monitors, @jacob-mckay's answer is the way to go.

Comment: I agree, not that I have a bias toward my own answer or anything :P I haven't played with android studio in long enough of a time to see if he can have two package explorers though, where there's a will and a little bit of time theres usually a way

Comment: Perhaps this should be migrated to SuperUser.SE?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider changing your accepted answer to @JacobMcKay 's?  As I see it, his suggestion does exactly what you intended to do.

Comment: Hi OP ! Can you tell me how you did it with the second picture ? I accidently did it once but can seem to repeat the process. Thanks !

Comment: I'd love the functionality the OP described

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Right click on tab of the file and click "Split vertical / Horizontal"

[image]

After splitting, you can just drag one of the tab titles to the second monitor - it will open up a new window. You can then edit the same file in two separate windows

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that helps a bit, but I want to have two separate windows, each with their own Title Bar, etc.

Comment: Impossible. Why do you need this ?

Comment: Then I can edit two files at the same time, and easily switch those two files. I also have two monitors, so I can't have the split-screened window spread across both monitors.

Comment: I would think this is just not possible, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I need two separate windows so I can have logcat on my right monitor and the IDE on my center one.

Comment: nice tip!!! thanks.. Is it possible to split two project in one window like this? :P

Answer (score 39):

If you click and drag a file's tab out of your current window (over onto the desktop, for example), the file will open in a new window.  However, this window doesn't seem to have the whole package explorer, console etc.

Although, if you click on the gear on any of the modules, you can uncheck 'pinned' mode and you'll be free to move them around your two monitors just like the window you created above.

Comment: Looking at the OP's comment on Marco's answer, this method should be more viable for use with multiple monitors since it opens a new window?

Comment: For me, unchecking "Pinned mode" makes it disappear when I defocus it.

Comment: This doesn't work at all (Mac). I'm using 2 monitors and if someone knows how I get this to work, he'll get the up vote. :-)

Comment: When I wrote this answer in 2014 I had a Windows machine.  Once I get my  Mac set up in the next couple days I'll take a look again.  It looks like there is a 'floating mode' option on the dockable windows that seems to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Android studio on my Mac seems to behave the same way as it does on Windows so not sure what you mean by "This doesn't work at all".  My suggestion works, but I still don't see a solution to the original question of having two fully function Android Studio IDES running and having them pointed to the same project.

Answer (score 7):

**Window -> Editor Tabs -> Split Vertically**

if you don't use files tabs

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split tabs of android studio project beetween monitors, you can rigthclick to tab(*project, debug, terminal etc*) and check the **"floating mode" option**.

See the image: [Floating mode tab option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntEGL.png)

After that you can drag this tab  between your monitors as new window.

Comment: When I place it on another monitor, then click Android Studio, then click the new window again, the new window snaps back to the original monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just make a copy of android studio & run it side / side? You can run different versions of android studio side/side.. Maybe that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the tab outside the current window.

Answer (score 0):

right click on tab and click on windowed mode, it will open up a new window.

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way of doing this (but you will not be able to save in the same project) is to make a `copy of the project folder and open it in Android Studio`.